# When bootstrap dropdown is clicked/opened the icon changes to represent its open

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've had a go using some Javascript, obviously without success. I imagine this would be a good function to build into future versions of bootstrap. Ideally I would prefer to use CSS to change the icon to an alternative upon clicking the dropdown. - http://bootply.com/67306

```
            <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle tablet-home-drop" data-toggle="dropdown">All Destinations <i class="icon-align-justify"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu drop-hover">
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#">More options</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#">More options</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#">More options</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to change where on the sprite the image points to when the dropdown is open.You'll have to find/set your own background position.

Example:

```
.tablet-home-drop > .icon-align-justify {
    margin-left: 45px;
}
.dropdown.open .tablet-home-drop > .icon-align-justify {
    background-position:-48px -72px;
}
```